# My Unity got stuck while building the projects

Tags: unity-game-engine, build

I'm new to this. I tried implementing Facebook SDK yesterday and was successful with it. But after that, I wasn't able to build my project. The Facebook thing wanted me to choose an android SDK. I chose the location where Android SDK was placed. And yet it wasn;t building the project. I downloaded new SDK's from Android Studio's SDK Manager gave that location. Searched Stack / UnityAnswers. Everyone said it was stuck at build scene 0. But mine feels different. And when this build is stuck at this stage (as in the image attached below). If i open my task manager its says unity not responding. I also tried giving the SDK location what unity recommends it still gets stuck at this point as shown in image below.

Point where my build is stuck:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Facebook SDK for Unity is quite broken. [290 open issues atm](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-for-unity/issues) and they never respond to any of them, they just mark them closed them without reading them it seems. It is usually extremely difficult to get it to work, especially when there are other SDKs involved.
My advice is don't use it, if possible. Save yourself a huge amount of pain if you can.
That being said, last time I used it this was the fix that worked for me.

1. Using the PlayServicesResolve, Resolve libraries
2. Do not Delete Resolved Libraries

Then change proguard and gradle like this:

Proguard:

```
-keep public class com.facebook.**{public *; } -keep public class com.facebook.internal.**{ public *; }
```

In Gradle we commented out a few libraries as follows:

```
`// Android Resolver Repos End
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0' 
// Android Resolver Dependencies Start
    //implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1' // Facebook.Unity.Editor.AndroidSupportLibraryResolver.addSupportLibraryDependency
    //implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1' // Facebook.Unity.Editor.AndroidSupportLibraryResolver.addSupportLibraryDependency
    //implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1' // Facebook.Unity.Editor.AndroidSupportLibraryResolver.addSupportLibraryDependency

    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.0.0' // Assets/IronSource/Editor/ISFacebookAdapterDependencies.xml:8
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:[7.1.0, 8)' // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:6
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[7.1.0, 8)' // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:8
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1' // Facebook.Unity.Editor.AndroidSupportLibraryResolver.addSupportLibraryDependency
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-gamingservices:[7.1.0, 8)' // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:9
    implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0' // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:4
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:[7.1.0, 8)' // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:5
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[7.1.0, 8)' // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:7
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.4.0' // Assets/IronSource/Editor/ISAdMobAdapterDependencies.xml:8
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0' // Assets/IronSource/Editor/IronSourceSDKDependencies.xml:17
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.2.1' // Assets/IronSource/Editor/IronSourceSDKDependencies.xml:25
// Android Resolver Dependencies End
**DEPS**}`
```

Comment: Where can I find both the gradle file and proguard file

Comment: Not a fan either but tbh all closed issues seem to have a t least one comment and 50% are closed by the reporters themselves .. so I would not claim they shut close them without reading ;)

Comment: @IcyThug buried in android build settings there is tickboxes for custom gradle and custim proguard file.. if you tick those boxes the files will appear in your project